# Bootstrap Carousel Transitions and Prev/Next Buttons no action

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create image transition with next/prev arrow and bulletin using the following code. When I click the arrows or Bulletin, there is no action. Arrows & Bulletin display is not working.

```
<div id="screenshots-carousel" class="screenshots-carousel top-padding-80 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.8s" data-screenshot="carousel" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.8s; animation-name: fadeIn;"
<div id="screenshots-carousel-content" class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal" data-carousel="content">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item swiper-slide-active" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;">
    <img src="img/scr/c1.jpg" alt="Screenshots 1">
    <a href="img/scr/c1.jpg" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item swiper-slide-next" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;">
     <img src="img/scr/c2.jpg" alt="Screenshots 2"><a href="img/scr/c2.jpg" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;"><img src="img/scr/c3.jpg" alt="Screenshots 3"><a href="img/scr/c3.jpg" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i></a>
  </div>
<div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;">
   <img src="img/scr/d1.png" alt="Screenshots 4"><a href="img/scr/d1.png" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i> </a>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;">
 <img src="img/scr/d2.png" alt="Screenshots 1"><a href="img/scr/d2.png" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide screenshot-item" style="width: 227.5px; margin-right: 30px;">
<img src="img/scr/d2.png" alt="Screenshots 2"><a href="img/scr/d2.png" class="zoom-overlay fs-lightbox-element" data-lightbox="yes"><i class="plus-sign"></i></a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
<div id="screenshots-carousel-pagination" class="bullet-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable" data-carousel="pagination">
 <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span></div>
   <div id="screenshots-carousel-nav-prev" class="arrow-control prev swiper-button-disabled" data-carousel="prev"></div>
  <div id="screenshots-carousel-nav-next" class="arrow-control next" data-carousel="next"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `>` here: `<div id="screenshots-carousel" class="screenshots-carousel top-padding-80 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.8s" data-screenshot="carousel" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.8s; animation-name: fadeIn;"`

Comment: @dippas : Actually I just copied the code from file. So it would be missing. I just wanna know that in which file to find this class "class="screenshots-carousel top-padding-80 wow fadeIn" .. Either Bootsrap or style.